# Помощь с массивом байт

Tags: c#

есть массив. В нем хранится массив значений допустим {1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1}. с 0 элемента массива по 3 записан "как бы" год, с 4 по 7 - неделя. Мне нужно это как то правильно вытягивать эти значения по отдельности и отобржать

Comment: набор слов какой-то. Опишите проблему конкретнее

Comment: у меня есть массив. В нем хранится массив значений допустим {1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1}.
с 0 элемента массива по 3 записан "как бы" год, с 4 по 7 - неделя. Мне нужно это как то правильно вытягивать эти значения по отдельности и отобржать на форме...

Comment: ну а int тут при чем? И что вы подразумеваете под "отображать на форме"?

Comment: @DreamChild. Да

Comment: Sergey Khrolenko что "да"?

Comment: Что бы числа были представлены не в бинарном виде, а например в int или string...

Comment: Массив байт? Или число типа `int`? Как конкретно определён тип данных?

Comment: послушайте, Сергей, неужели из вас каждое слово надо клещами вытаскивать? Сформулируйте вопрос нормально пожалуйста.  Что значит "отображать на форме"? При чем тут год/неделя?  Если вам нужно представить массив в виде интов, что мешает привести их неявно из byte в int?

Comment: Я постарался логично объяснить проблему. 
1)Если я явно преобразую в int или байт то он просто все преобразует в одно число.
2)Мне нужно что бы он преобразовал в 2 отдельных числа. Причем масив имеет бинарный код.

Comment: Не обязательно отвечать на комментарии. Переформулируйте вопрос. Сейчас тут набросились десяток опытных людей и никто не может понять что именно вы хотите сделать. Вот вы привели пример {1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1} а какому году это соотвествует и какой неделе? Как вообще это посчитать если не на C# а просто на бумажке с карандашом?

Comment: Вот даже интересно, правильно-ли я понял. Элементы массива - это биты двух чисел. 1111 - год; 1110 - неделя. Меня только ооооочень сильно смущает что номер недели никак не влезет в 4 бита (даже если ногой заталкивать). Надо где-то еще два найти (посмотрите, может под столом завалялись :)).

Comment: @tutankhamun. Вы все правильно поняли. В году 52 недели. Все отлично влезает. (0 1 1 1)

Comment: Сергей, каждое ваше объяснение только еще больше запутывает. У вас очень плохо получается объяснять. Вы пишете ")Если я явно преобразую в int или байт то он просто все преобразует в одно число". Что преобразуется в одно число? Как вы преобразовываете?  

Далее вы пишете "Мне нужно что бы он преобразовал в 2 отдельных числа" кто "он"? В какие два отдельных числа? По какому принципу?

Далее "масив имеет бинарный код" Какой бинарный код? У вас же массив байтов, не так ли? Если хотите какой-то помощи, то пожалуйста потрудитесь написать нормальный вопрос, не порождающий тысячу других вопросов

Comment: Ну допустим есть массив `array1 = {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1};` Год посчитать дело нехитрое `year = array1[0] << 3 + array1[1] << 2 + array1[2] << 1 + array1`. Аналогично можно посчитать и номер недели, но я вам точно говорю: в 4 бита поместится только число от 0 до 15. 52 не поместится.

Comment: @tutankhamun, там же байты, а не биты.

Comment: @Qwertiy Я тут заглянул в соседний вопрос ТС. Сдается мне, товарищ читает побитово пакет из RS485. В первой "редакции" текста данного вопроса есть кусочек про 0 и 1. PS. Я тут скоро сдам экзамен на телепата :)

Answer (score 1):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.bitconverter.toint32(v=vs.110).aspx

```
int year = BitConverter.ToInt32(b, 0), week = BitConverter.ToInt32(b, 4);
```

---

> Может быть, укажите в ответе, как вы поняли вопрос?

Ok. Есть массив из 8 байт, который фактически содержит 2 значения int32. Первые 4 байта - год, следующие 4 - неделя. Как поместить данные из этого массива в две int'овые переменные?

Comment: Вроде бы не оно, у ТС кажется в массив разбросаны биты.

Comment: @VladD, про биты откуда-то взял  
tutankhamun, больше никаких упоминаний бит на странице нет.

Comment: В вопросе: _В нем хранится массив значений допустим {1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1}_

Comment: @VladD, "Помощь с массивом _байт_" - заголовок темы.

Comment: Это да. Но мы уже выяснили, что вопрос сформулирован _не очень понятно_. Может быть, укажите в ответе, как вы поняли вопрос? (Или приведите примерные данные.)

Comment: @VladD, указал.